# Run tracert from an azure app service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, kudu

we are trying to debug a connectivity issue and I can't seem to run tracert from my azure app service (azure website) instance. If I use the kudu cmd console and run tracert www.ibm.com I get the error "unable to contact IP driver. Error code 1753"

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Azure web app service intances block ICMP. So you can not use Ping and Tracert on powershell and CMD. However, I recommend you can use ***`tcpping`*** on Azure website kudu console.

```
PS D:\home> tcpping www.hotmail.com
Connected to www.hotmail.com:80, time taken: 204ms
Connected to www.hotmail.com:80, time taken: 140ms
Connected to www.hotmail.com:80, time taken: 140ms
Connected to www.hotmail.com:80, time taken: 140ms
Complete: 4/4 successfull attempts (100%). Average success time: 156ms
PS D:\home>
```

Comment: What about tracert? Any alternative to being able to execute this?